# How to animate an object with similar ghosting effect?

Tags: animation, animation-nodes

Can anyone give me any ideas onw how to recreate the effect as seen in this gif?

[image]

I would imagine it being simple, like having a single stick as the primary object, animating it along a path, and then somehow telling Blender how to leave a "ghost image" of that object every X number of frames.

I can do the first two parts, but the ghosting effect is something I am a bit lost on. Any tips would be appreciated! :)

Thank you!

Comment: Please embed the image into the question directly…

Comment: Updated, sorry.

Comment: Okay. Hmm, wondering about what this looks like in 3D since the trailing end doesn’t look like it just gets smaller. But as for the ghost effect, I might try using an array, and making sure the distance the stick moves each frame is the same distance between the sticks of the array. May not work